# GDAL upgrade causes errors in uploading shapefiles with ogr2ogr

Tags: postgis, gdal, postgresql

After upgrading my GDAL version to 3.1.4, I am unable to upload shapefiles to a local postgres database by using ogr2ogr.  PostGIS is already installed and I am able to connect and run queries successfully on PGAdmin.  However, I am no longer able to upload shapefiles through the terminal.

The following command used to work:

```
ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=localhost password=password dbname=postgres  port
=5432" USA_counties.shp -nln usa_counties
```

But now the following errors are thrown when I run it:

```
ERROR 1: ERROR:  could not load library "/usr/local/lib/postgresql/postgis-3.so": dlopen(/usr/local/lib/postgresql/postgis-3.so, 10): Symbol not found: _hash_bytes
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/postgresql/postgis-3.so
  Expected in: /usr/local/opt/postgresql/bin/postgres
 in /usr/local/lib/postgresql/postgis-3.so

ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_identify: Cannot find proj.db
ERROR 1: ERROR:  could not load library "/usr/local/lib/postgresql/postgis-3.so": dlopen(/usr/local/lib/postgresql/postgis-3.so, 10): Symbol not found: _hash_bytes
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/postgresql/postgis-3.so
  Expected in: /usr/local/opt/postgresql/bin/postgres
 in /usr/local/lib/postgresql/postgis-3.so

ERROR 1: ERROR:  could not load library "/usr/local/lib/postgresql/postgis-3.so": dlopen(/usr/local/lib/postgresql/postgis-3.so, 10): Symbol not found: _hash_bytes
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/postgresql/postgis-3.so
  Expected in: /usr/local/opt/postgresql/bin/postgres
 in /usr/local/lib/postgresql/postgis-3.so

ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_create_from_database: Cannot find proj.db
```

Any ideas as to what steps need to be taken to successfully load `postgis-3.so`?

Edit:

When accessing

`/usr/local/opt/postgresql/bin/postgres` in the terminal, the following message appears:

`postgres does not know where to find the server configuration file. You must specify the --config-file or -D invocation option or set the PGDATA environment variable.`

Comment: does `/usr/local/lib/postgresql/postgis-3.so` exist?

Comment: It seems that proj.db is not found. Does your gdal find it? Can you do for example `gdalwarp -f gpkg -t_srs epsg:3857 output.gpkg USA_counties.shp`?

Comment: @IanTurton yes `/usr/local/lib/postgresql/postgis-3.so` points to `postgis-3.so -> ../../Cellar/postgis/3.0.3/lib/postgresql/postgis-3.so`

Comment: I would expect that to be a link to a file in the same directory. How did you install/upgrade gdal?

Comment: I upgraded gdal with homebrew